# Create View of two identical tables from two seperate systems to return only unique records

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, view

I have two systems running the same software off identical databases. For reporting, I need to report on the ticket tables. 
I linked the two servers and created a union between the two ticket tables but I am still getting duplicate records. The software does replicate ticket data betwen the two systems however this is a report for "pre" replication which means this

I need ALL tickets in ticket table A and I need only records from ticket table B that I do not already have. The ticket number is unique in this instance. I am using several colums from these tables like, vehicle ID, Customer Name, Price, Quantity, etc. And many in formulas at well. To name them all would really be extensive. Is there another way to take ALL columns from both tables into a view but only see distnct records

I tried to create the view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW  vw_combinedtickettable as
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Ticket
UNION
SELECT *  from LinkedServer.Database2.dbo.ticket
```

Thinking using just `union` and not `union all` would work and it isn't.

Any help would be great.

Comment: have you tried NOT IN or DOESNT EXIST?

Comment: `union` should be returning unique rowsets, while `union all` would return duplicates. Is there some other column that's not identical between your two databases, all else being equal?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    dbo.Ticket
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    LinkedServer.Database2.dbo.ticket
WHERE   ticketNumber NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  ticketNumber
        FROM    dbo.Ticket
        )
```

Comment: Im still getting duplicates using the above SQL. I dont understand why. I can't supporess it because that causes trouble when numbers are 34555 and 1234555. it will suppress both.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
    CREATE VIEW vw_combinedtickettable AS
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Ticket t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.* FROM dbo.Ticket t1
    LEFT JOIN LinkedServer.Database2.dbo.ticket t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
    AND t1.id IS NULL
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this and it threw an error. Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'TicketType' in view or function vw_combinedtickettable is specified more than once.

Comment: Of course it would sorry,  not able to test it atm. I have amended my answer hopefully that should give you the desired output.